# ¿Cómo actualizar un campo en otra tabla al modificar otro campo en una tabla distinta?

Tags: sql

Estoy trabajando un pequeño sistema *modular* donde los usuarios que trabajan en la empresa tambien pueden ser consumidores o usuarios finales de la aplicación, pero en dado caso, esos empleados dejan de trabajar en esa empresa, pero no son privados de utilizar el software, sólo pierden esos accesos de administración.

Los registros de administración no son eliminados hasta despues de un año, por lo que los registros se quedan ahí en caso de que el empleado vuelva, por ello la eliminación solo debe ocurrir una vez por año.

Cada usuario que se registra en la aplicación tiene un registro en la tabla `Profiles` y el campo `HasAdminRights` ajustado a cero/`false`, pero si este mismo usuario empieza a trabajar en la compañía *(Caso remoto, no imposible)*, entonces se le crea una entrada en la tabla `AdminRights` y se ajusta `HasAdminRights` a 1/`true` para tener el acceso a las herramientas administrativas del sistema.

Estas son los posibles significados de los valores de ambos campos:

- En un caso normal, `HasAdminRights` debe ser 1 y `Revoked` debe ser 0.
- Si un empleado deja de trabajar en la empresa, `HasAdminRights` pasa a ser 0 y `Revoked` es 1.

Este es el esquema que llevo de la base de datos:

```
--
-- Customer profile table.
--
create table Profiles (
  [ID]                  int 
  identity(1,1)         primary key  not null,

  -- ... Algunos campos ...

  [DisabledAdminRights] bit          not null default 1,
  [RegisterDate]        datetime     not null,
  [LastLoginDate]       datetime     not null
);

--
-- Administrator rights.
--
create table AdminRights (
  [ID] int 
  identity(1,1)       primary key not null,
  [ProfileID]         int         not null unique,
  -- ... Otros campos ...
  [AccessGrant]       datetime    not null,
  [Revoked]           bit         not null default 0,
  constraint fkProfID4EmpRights foreign key ([ProfileID]) references Profiles(ID)
  on update cascade on delete cascade -- No idea whether this is good or not.
);
```

En resumen, lo que necesito saber es ¿Cómo cambiar el valor del campo `[Revoked]` en la tabla `AdminRights` cuando el campo `DisabledAdminRights` de la tabla `Profiles` se cambia a `1` o `true`?

He intentado con un Stored Procedure:

```
create procedure SetRevoked
  @ProfID
as
begin
  update AdminRights set Revoked=1 where ProfileID = @ProfID
end
```

Pero no se como hacer que se ejecute cada vez que el usuario hace esa modificación en su perfil.

Comment: Y ¿has probado con un trigger en la tabla Profiles?

Comment: Mi fuerte no es SQL :^)

Comment: Bueno, ahí Lamak te lo dejó armadito ^_~ jijiji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma de hacer es con un `AFTER UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Cambia_DisablesAdminRights]
   ON [dbo].[Profiles]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (DisabledAdminRights) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE A 
        SET A.Revoked = CASE WHEN I.DisabledAdminRights = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        FROM [dbo].[AdminRights] A
        INNER JOIN INSERTED I 
            ON A.ProfileID = I.ID 
        WHERE A.Revoked = I.DisabledAdminRights;
    END 
END
```

Comment: Está buenísimo :) Oye, pero el NOCOUNT al final está bien que quede en ON?

Comment: debería ser válido sólo para el trigger, la verdad

Comment: Ah, oki, no sabía ;)